# C++ dynamic_cast - polymorphic requirement and downcasting

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, downcast

In the following code, while constructing `obj` in case 1, we construct a `derived` class object too, but its member functions are just inaccessible to `obj`. So while downcasting (i.e., in case 2), using `obj` as source, we have the constructed `derived` in it already. Why would `obj` need to be polymorphic?

If I confused you with my above description, why doesn't `obj` need to be polymorphic when upcasting, but while downcasting it *does* need to be polymorphic while using `dynamic_cast`?

```
class base
{
public:
    base()
    {
        cout<< " \n base constructor \n";
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    derived()
    {
        cout << " \n derived constructor \n";
    }
};

base *obj = dynamic_cast<base*> (new derived); // case 1: explicitly upcasting
derived *OBJ = dynamic_cast<derived*> (obj);   // case 2: error
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From 5.2.7/1 [expr.dynamic.cast] :

> The result of the expression `dynamic_cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression v to type
>   T.
>
> [...]
>
> If T is "pointer to *cv1* B" and v has type "pointer to *cv2* D" such that B is a base class of D, the result is a
>   pointer to the unique B sub-object of the D object pointed to by v.
>
> [...]
>
> **Otherwise**, v shall be a pointer to or an lvalue of a polymorphic type.

The standard even provides the following example which illustrates that the polymorphic type requirement does not stand for derived to base conversion :

```
struct B {};
struct D : B {};
void foo(D* dp)
{
    B* bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(dp); // equivalent to B* bp = dp;
}
```

Answer (score 30):

In order for **dynamic_cast** to work the object needs to be polymorphic. The reason for this is that **dynamic_cast** needs somewhere to store the type information that is will use to perform the cast, and it does this by storing the information alongside the vtable for the class. In order for there to be a vtable you need to make at least one of your methods virtual.

The easiest way around this is to flag the base class destructor as virtual.

Upcasting (ie derived to base) doesn't needs a cast as the compiler is able to check that the cast would work at compile time. However, the same isn't true when downcasting.

Comment: you could downcast with `static_cast` in this example. You know at compile time that `obj` contains the right class. The use for dynamic_cast is when you don't know at compile time if the object is derived of another one. Eg when you get a pointer out of a function and need to check if the returned object belongs to a certain class. (But you are right, they must be virtual.)

Comment: I still don't see why it has to be polymorphic, ie. why it has to store the information "alongside the vtable", why it can not store it somewhere else, without the vtable?

Comment: @adamm Becase C++, like C, strives to ensure you don't pay for something you don't need. The vtable provides an ideal place to store this. Other alternatives would involve increasing the size of an object just to store the information that may not be needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
B* b = new D();
D* d = dynamic_cast<D*>(b);
```

In the above example most compilers would implement dynamic cast by checking whether the vtable pointer of b points to the vtable of the derived class D or not.
If yes, it simply returns the address of b as the return value otherwise it returns a nullptr.
This is what possibly goes on behind the scenes when a dynamic cast executes :-

```
class car
{
    public:
    virtual void drive()
    {
         std::cout <<"car"<<std::endl;
    }
};
class toyota: public car
{
    public:
    virtual void drive()
    {
        std::cout <<"toyota"<<std::endl;
    }
};

class honda: public car
{
    public:
        virtual void drive()
    {
        std::cout <<"honda"<<std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename Tderived>
Tderived* dynamicCast(void* pBase)
{
    //compare the vptr of the class pointed by pBase with a temporary Tderived class. 
    //If vptr of pBase and vptr of Tderived() are pointing to the same vtable 
    //then it can be safely deduced that pBase is indeed pointing to an instance of Tderived
    if (*(int**)pBase == *(int**)&Tderived())
    {
        return (Tderived*)pBase;
    }
    else
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}


int main()
{
    car* pCar;
    honda hondaCar;
    toyota toyotaCar;

    pCar = &toyotaCar;

    honda* pHonda = dynamicCast<honda>(pCar);
    if (nullptr != pHonda)
    {
        pHonda->drive();
    }
    else
    {
        toyota* pToyota = dynamicCast<toyota>(pCar);
        if (nullptr != pToyota)
        {
            pToyota->drive();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if the class is not polymorphic, there is no way for the compiler to find whether pCar is pointing to honda or toyota car. Note that this is just one of the ways to implement dynamic_cast as the C++ standard does not talk anything about vtables.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic_cast

- It is used to cast a base pointer
  into a derived pointer. If the base
  pointer doesn't point to an object of
  the type of the derived, it returns
- It is used to cast a base reference
  into a derived reference. If the
  reference isn't pointing to an object
  of the derived, it throws
  std::bad_cast.
- It can be considered the checked cast
  equivalent to static_cast, in that it
  checks whether the object pointed to
  really is of the derived type.

You must read more about Dynamic_cast (with example) [there](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).