# c++ can't copy node because of polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am working with a node tree and I want to copy a node and all of it's children but I can't because of polymorphism.

```cpp
class Node 
{
    Node(const Node& other)
    {
        // not sure what to do
    }
    ~Node() virtual
    {
        for (auto child: children)
            delete child;
    }

    vector<Node*> children;
}

class Node1 
{
    // node1
}
class Node2
{
    // node2
}
```

Children in node is a mix of node1 and node2.

I have tried using new Node exception that does not work because then it does not have enough space for the polymorphised nodes. The only way that I can think to do this is with malloc but that seems a little crude.

Comment: Try an if statemt with `dynamic_cast`. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644753/c-dynamic-cast-polymorphic-requirement-and-downcasting) might help.

Comment: Aren't `Node1` and `Node2` supposed to derive from `Node`? Your description implies that, but it's not in your code.

Comment: Polymorphism only works with pointers or references, so you've made a good start by using `vector<Node*>`. But there must also be a common parent class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone as derived object in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939570/how-to-clone-as-derived-object-in-c) (assuming the derived relations I inferred were supposed to be present in the code)

Comment: P.S. the C++ replacement for `malloc` is `new`.

Comment: FYI, a vector of "Node*" (on my Ubuntu 64, g++, system) is only 24 bytes (in automatic memory), regardless of how many elements or size of elements.    All the bulk of data resides in dynamic memory.

Comment: @MarkRansom P.P.S. The modern C++ replacement for `new` is `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @L.F. I wouldn't presume to guess at appropriate pointer ownership from such a small code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an abstract base class, like this

```
class i_node
{
    public: 

    virtual i_node() = 0;
    virtual ~i_node(){}
}
```

And make Node, Node1 and Node2 all inherit from i_node, with the children vector containing pointers to i_nodes instead of a derived class.

```
vector<i_node*> children;
```